# How to Get data that been clicked into next page in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one with id, questions and other with q_id, answers. i have linked both of them using the ID from question to q_id of answers. now i m trying to add a link to question, where if anyone clicks on the question it would go to the .php file where he can only see the selected question and its answer instead of all the Q&A in both tables.

Script 1::

```
`<?php`

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM input ORDER BY date DESC"; 
                             `$result = $conn->query($sql);

                                if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
                                $index = 0; 
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                                  $index++;`
    <a href='answ.php?id = " . $row['id'] . "'><?php echo $row["question"]; ?> </a>
```

Script 2

```
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM input WHERE id =" .$_GET["id"];
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                $index = 0; 
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                                  $index++; `
`<B><big><font color= #ba4a00> Q:</font></big><?php echo $row["question"]; ?> </B>`
```

I m getting a error like..

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\the_database\answ.php
>   on line 549

where lin 549 is script2 line#1 and

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\the_database\answ.php on line 558

Any Help is Appreciated..

Comment: Check out [PDO's prepare()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) for a secure way of inserting parameters info a query.

Comment: Check out Query Strings and PHP's [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)-super global.

Comment: can you guys give me an example of it..

Comment: Remove the spaces in `answ.php?id = `. Keep an eye on SQL-Injection - your code is obviously vulnerable ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As display in first script, you are not getting any result of index: id, and you have passed parameter in URL.
Now in second script you are using id as get parameter. But as you know you don't have any index named id, you can't get id from URL, and when you are trying to run the query there's a query error and it returns non-object.

replace following line:

```
<a href='answ.php?id = " . $row['id'] . "'><?php echo $row["question"]; ?> </a>
```

with:

```
<a href='answ.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'><?php echo $row["question"]; ?> </a>
```

Comment: actually i am following this article... http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson20.php   can you spare some time to look at it. i did exactly what it said...

Comment: Right, but in your case, its clearly shows that you don't get any index named id from first script.

Comment: where is this test server.. in stack exchange itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122970/discussion-between-kinjalmistry-and-user6779766).

Answer (score 0):

all thing you need to do is clear space :
replace:

```
<a href='answ.php?id = " . $row['id'] . "'><?php echo $row["question"]; ?> </a>
```

with:

```
<a href='answ.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'><?php echo $row["question"]; ?> </a>
```

that's all